# Calculating file MD5 in Angular, but getting Azure Storage's MD5 signature

Tags: angular, typescript, azure, md5

I'm using `ts-md5` to generate an hexadecimal string of a file, selected by the user.

```
import { Md5 } from 'ts-md5/dist/md5';

let md5 = new Md5();
md5.appendByteArray(file); //file here is a object of File type, selected by user.
console.log(md5.end());
```

This will, for example, yield: `d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e`

I've tried to encrypt this string with many algos and never wind up with that Azure Storage itself produces for the same file, which looks like: `KUK/q7PQUzK2brEo4IQs/w==`

I've also tried reading the file through different methods such as

```
var fr = new FileReader();
fr.onload = function (content) {
    let md5 = Md5.hashStr(fr.result);
    console.log(btoa(md5)); //I've read that Azure Storage base64 encodes to get their output
}

fr.readAsText(file);
```

I've tried `readAsText`, `readAsArrayBuffer` to no avail. I've never end up with what Microsoft has.

Any ideas ?

Comment: "KUK/q7PQUzK2brEo4IQs/w==" - this looks like base64 to me.

Comment: If I base64 decode this, I end up with: `)BS2n(,` Wth is this ?

Comment: random bytes. Just what you would expect to find in a md5 hash. Your string "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e" is also 16 bytes, but hex-encoded.

Comment: So I need to convert that hex string to....? and base64 encode that ?

Comment: I tried doing that, but the resulting byte arrays don't match. Could it be difference in endianness between your machine and azure? Or simply different contents were hashed? No idea.